# Diferença entre o "Pixel real" e o "Pixel de referência" no CSS

Tags: html, css, front-end

Recentemente me deparei com duas definições distintas de pixel no CSS. O pixel "real", a junção de pontos luminosos rgb em nossa tela, e o pixel de "referência" usado no CSS, sendo ele maior que o pixel real. Qual seria o calculo usado para a criação de um pixel de referência e por que ele foi criado?

Answer (score -3):

O pixel de referência é usado no CSS para garantir que as dimensões de um elemento na página sejam consistentes independentemente do dispositivo ou tamanho da tela em que a página é exibida. Ele foi criado para ajudar a lidar com diferenças nas densidades de pixels entre dispositivos.

A densidade de pixels é a quantidade de pixels em uma área específica de uma tela, geralmente medida em pixels por polegada (ppi). Dispositivos com alta densidade de pixels têm mais pixels em uma área menor, o que geralmente os torna mais nítidos. Dispositivos com baixa densidade de pixels têm menos pixels em uma área maior, o que geralmente os torna menos nítidos.

Se um elemento é definido com uma largura de 100 pixels no CSS, ele aparecerá como 100 pixels em uma tela com baixa densidade de pixels, mas aparecerá muito menor em uma tela com alta densidade de pixels. Para contornar isso, o pixel de referência foi criado. Ele é calculado com base na densidade de pixels da tela. Em dispositivos com alta densidade de pixels, um pixel de referência é maior do que um pixel real, para que o elemento apareça no tamanho correto. Já em dispositivos com baixa densidade de pixels, um pixel de referência é menor do que um pixel real, para que o elemento não apareça muito grande.

A forma de calcular o pixel de referência é:

```html
Pixel de Referência = 
Pixel Real / Densidade de Pixels
```

É importante ressaltar que, recentemente, com o aumento do uso de telas touch e dispositivos móveis, o conceito de pixel de referência vem sendo cada vez menos utilizado e sendo substituido pelo uso de unidades de medida relativas como rem, em, vw e vh que não se baseiam em densidade de pixels e sim em tamanho relativo a tela do dispositivo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).